# How to access Meteor.users() fields from the client?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-publications

I want to access users emails in from the client,
here is what I have done, in the server side:

```
Meteor.publish('userList', function (){ 
  return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields:{emails: 1, profile: 1}});
});
```

In the client side:

```
Template.usersManagement.onCreated(function () {
    var self = this;
    self.autorun(function() {
        self.subscribe('userList');
    });
});
```

And the template helper to retrieve the users:

```
Template.usersManagement.helpers({
    allUsers: function() {
        console.log(Meteor.users.find({}).fetch())
        return Meteor.users.find({}).fetch()
    }
})
```

In the `usersManagement` template:

```
{{#each allUsers}}

    <h1>{{this.emails.address}}</h1>
    <h1>{{this.profile.name}}</h1>
                    
{{/each}}
```

The users names are displayed but the email isn't and no errors showing in the console.

Here is the look on how the users stored in the database:

```
{
        "_id" : "m7admvZc32Jr3SeiE",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-12-27T21:24:48.927Z"),
        "services" : {
                "password" : {
                        "bcrypt" : "$2a$10$wv6KsRp6s91A.0mHH89Q0eT3jrZmJjKJhw8SIH9c8c8OpwMrXyGMC"
                }
        },
        "emails" : [
                {
                        "address" : "222@222.com",
                        "verified" : false
                }
        ],
        "profile" : {
                "name" : "222",
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-12-27T21:24:48.707Z"),
                "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-12-27T21:24:48.707Z"),
                "group" : "admin"
        },
        "status" : {
                "online" : false
        }
}
```

My question is, how can I retrieve the emails of the users?

**EDIT**

Here is how the emails are retrieved (from the console):

[image: emails]

There is another field (0) below the emails. I tried `this.emails.0.address` it didn't work (desperate attempt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your desperate attempt almost nailed it, try this:

```
this.emails.[0].address
```

Comment: I think this.emails[0].address will be right syntax to access it.

Comment: @VinayChaudhary actually it worked as Behrouz mentioned with emails.[0].address!

Answer (score 1):

An item in the `Meteor.users` collection store [emails as an array](https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#multiple-emails), for you to be able to store more than one email-address per user. So since it is so, the right way would be:

```
<h1>{{this.emails[0].address}}</h1>
```